# Remove reoccuring lines from text file with enhanced performance

Tags: performance, matlab, parsing, file-io

I have the following **performance issue** concerning large text file input (~500k lines) and **subsequent data parsing**.

Consider a text file `data.txt` having the following exemplary structure with the pecularity that the **two header lines can reappear somewhere in the text file**:

```
Name Date Val1 val2
--- ------- ---- ----
BA 2013-09-07 123.123 1232.22
BA 2013-09-08 435.65756 2314.34
BA 2013-09-09 234.2342 21342.342
```

The code I wrote and which is working is the following:

```
%# Read in file using textscan, read all values as string

inFile = fopen('data.txt','r');
DATA = textscan(inFile, '%s %s %s %s');
fclose(inFile);

%# Remove the header lines everywhere in DATA:
%# Search indices of the first entry in first cell, i.e. 'Name', and remove 
%# all lines corresponding to those indices

[iHeader,~] = find(strcmp(DATA{1},DATA{1}(1)));
for i=1:length(DATA)
    DATA{i}(iHeader)=[];
end

%# Repeat again, the first entry corresponds now to '---'

[iHeader,~] = find(strcmp(DATA{1},DATA{1}(1)));
for i=1:length(DATA)
    DATA{i}(iHeader)=[];
end

%# Now convert the cells for column Val1 and Val2 in data.txt to doubles
%# since they have been read in as strings:

for i=3:4
    [A] = cellfun(@str2double,DATA{i});
    DATA{i} = A;
end
```

I chose to read in everything as a string in oder to be able to remove the remove the header lines everywhere in `DATA`.

Stopping the time tells me that the slowest part of the code is the conversion `[A] = cellfun(@str2double,DATA{i})` although `str2double` is already the faster choice compared to `str2num`. The second slowest part is `textscan`.

**The question is now, is there a faster way to deal with this problem?**

Please let me know if I should further clearify. And forgive me if there is a very obvious solution I haven't seen, I'm just working with Matlab for three weeks now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an option of `textscan` called `CommentStyle` that will skip part of your file (the repeated 2 headerlines in your case), and read your file in one function call.

As the [doc says](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html), `CommentStyle` can be used in 2 ways: a single string such as `'%'` to ignore characters following the string on the same line, or a cell array of two strings, such as `{'/*', '*/'}`, to ignore characters between the two strings (including end of lines). We will use the second option here: remove characters between `Name` and `-`. As the ending string consists of a repeated `-` character, we need to specify the whole string.

```
inFile = fopen('data.txt','r');
DATA = textscan(inFile, '%s %s %f %f', ...
      'Commentstyle', {'Name';'--- ------- ---- ----'});
fclose(inFile);
```

You can convert a date string into a meaningful number using `datenum`.

```
DATA_date = datenum(C{2})
```

Comment: This worked well for my data. Avoiding the usage of string to double conversion decreases the time by roughtly 60%!

Answer (score 2):

Although over the longer term it would be better if possible to fix your data acquisition to avoid this, you could take advantage of `HeaderLines` in textscan.

This example code will work but preallocate c3/c4 if possible (i.e. by estimating upper size bound and trimming zeros off afterwards).  Basically, on first calling `textscan` it will skip the first two lines, and continue until it hits a line incompatible with the format (e.g. midway through the repeated header), or until it reaches end of the file.  It remembers the position it got to, though.

The next time that `textscan` is called, it skips the rest of that line and the next whole line, then continues (until eof or another set of header lines, etc).  If you've reached the end of the file, textscan will run without error, but `length(data{3})` should be zero.

```
c3 = [];
c4 = [];
fid = fopen('data.txt');
data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %f %f','HeaderLines',2);
l = length(data{3});
while l>0  %stop when we hit eof
  c3 = [c3; data{3}];
  c4 = [c4; data{4}];
  data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %f %f','HeaderLines',2);
  l = length(data{3});
end
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot. I comparison to the answer by @Magla this does not require the specific from of the two (or gernerally N) header lines. For my code the solution by Magla was shorter to implement so I chose it as best fitting answer. Also, in terms of speed using `commentstyle` is 50% faster.